# Faceted Search With(out) Solr

Tags: php, solr, symfony-1.4, shared-hosting, faceted-search

I want to implement a [faceted search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search) for a project of mine. I'm using `PHP5`, `Mysql` and `Symfony 1.4`. Apparently the commnunity points to [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) which seems to do exactly what I want to accomplish.

The problem is that the website is going to be live on a hosting provider that doesn't allow me to setup `Solr` (it is a shared hosting environment and neither allows `Tomcat` nor `Solr` to be up-and-running).

So could you please give me directions on possible alternatives or if there is a way to setup `Solr` in such an environment?

**EDIT**
My hosting provider neither supports `SOLR` nor solutions as `opensolr`. In general I can't use my environment to connect to a process on the same server or a remote one.  It seems the only available option is to use [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.html). So does this support faceted searching? Or if you have another option in mind please share it! I feel being in the middle of nowhere!

**EDIT 2**
As this question is opened for about a week from the answers given so far I am surprised (and disappointed) that there is no library (*not* service) available in PHP to implement faceted search. It seems that either this needs to be implemented manually or use solutions provided below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance won't be great and don't discuss scaling, but you can always create a reverse HTTP tunnelling over HTTP. Basically, instead of the web server opening an outbound connection to the Solr server, it's the Solr server connecting to the web server to request jobs and to post job results.

What you'll need to do:

1. The browser post a search query, the query is simply queued in the database.
2. The reverse proxy periodically connects to the web server (over plain ol' port 80) to fetch a list of queries from the job queue, pass the queries to the Solr server, and POST the results back to the web server.
3. The browser periodically polls the web server for finished search result.

Bonus marks: if your server allows concurrent request processing, use [long polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to improve latency.

In short, bite the bullet and move to a decent host.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. In fact I didn't even now the existence of "Reverse HTTP tunneling". As you can imagine I can't use such a server on my pathetic environment...

Comment: @pankar: yes, the reverse proxy and the Solr server have to live outside your current server. But your current web server can stay as it is; management of the job queue can be written in plain ol' PHP without any fancy tricks. I'm not quite sure though which one is easier, implementing a home-brew faceted search or a home-brew job queueing.

Answer (score 2):

Change hosts, or host the Solr index elsewhere - for example, a quick search revealed http://www.opensolr.com/ provide Solr hosting, there are no doubt many others.

Comment: Thanks for your input. These solutions would require unblocked outbound connections on some port (i.e 8080). Something for which I'm not sure it's supported by my shared hosting environment. I'll drop them an email to ask them though. Moreover there might be performance issues in this setup. I am in favor of open-source solutions (even custom) on the same server (best case scenario)

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid Zend_Search_Lucene, it's not really fast. (Well it's pretty good given that it's implemented in Php and doesn't run as daemon)

Hosted Solr as Paul suggested sounds like a good alternative - if you are not willing to change host.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Like I said on my edit I simply can't use alternatives as opensolr because I can't establish an outbound connection to any port...!@#$ shared hosting...

Comment: Note that to talk to solr you only need Http, so you can go thrugh a Http Proxy if one is available.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is inter-process communication, http or SOAP/XML. shared hosting blocks outbound traffic for all ports.

Comment: @pankar: what kind of retarded shared hosting are you in? All of the shared hosting I've been with allows creating outbound HTTP traffic, and some even allow opening local ports for internal application servers like Solr. Save yourself some trouble and move to a decent host.

Comment: @Lie Ryan The official response I got from them is that they don't support outbound traffic and I need to move to another package in order to have this functionality... If this was my site I would have already done this...(move to a decent host)